# Modal dialog disappears after a couple seconds before user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to add sweetalert.js to my project. Once user clicks a refresh button, a dialog should popup asking for confirmation and if yes, action should perform, otherwise, it simply closes the dialog without doing anything.

So far I've made a function:

```
function refresh() {
        swal({
            title: "",
            type: "warning",
            text: "Do you want to proceed?",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes",
            cancelButtonText: "No"
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: true,
        });
```

and I'm calling it here

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Refresh", "Site", FormMethod.Post))
{  
   <button type="submit" onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
}
```

but when I click the button it just shows the dialog for a couple of seconds, dialog disappears and it auto refresh. Same goes when I click cancel or confirm buttons.

Comment: The function must `return false` to cancel `submit` event.

Comment: Where exactly am I suppose to add that?